# How to create custom, dynamic string sequence in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to dynamically build sequences containing dates/strings/numbers in SQL Server?

In my application, I want every order to have a unique identificator that is a sequence of: Type of order, Year, Month, Incrementing number

(ex: NO/2016/10/001, NO/2016/10/002)

where NO = "Normal order", 2016 is a year, 10 is a month and 001 is an incrementing number. The idea is that it is easier for employees to comunicate using these types of identificators (of course this sequence would not be primary key of database table)

I know that I could create a stored procedure that would take Order type as an argument and return the sequence, but I'm curious if there is any better way to do it.

Cheers!

Comment: Just curious.  Max 999 orders per month or year or until the end-of-time?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Per month but it's just an example. I wouldn't limit it to 999 per month in the real application of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `IDENTITY` column might have gaps. Just imagine an insert which is rollbacked out of any reason...

You could use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),OrderDate,112) ORDER BY OrderDate)` in order to start a sorted numbering starting with 1 for each month. What will be best is depending on the following question: Are there parallel insert operations?

As this *order name* should be unique, you might run into *unique-key-violations* where you'd need complex mechanisms to work around...

If it is possible for you to use the existing ID you might use a scalar function together with a computed column (might be declared `persistant`):

```
CREATE TABLE OrderType(ID INT,Name VARCHAR(100),Abbr VARCHAR(2));
INSERT INTO OrderType VALUES(1,'Normal Order','NO')
                           ,(2,'Special Order','SO');
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.OrderCaption(@OrderTypeID INT,@OrderDate DATETIME,@OrderID INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ISNULL((SELECT Abbr FROM OrderType WHERE ID=@OrderTypeID),'#NA')
         + '/' + CAST(YEAR(@OrderDate) AS VARCHAR(4))
         + '/' + REPLACE(STR(MONTH(@OrderDate),2),' ','0')
         + '/' + REPLACE(STR(@OrderID,5),' ','0')
END
GO


CREATE TABLE YourOrder
(
     ID INT IDENTITY
    ,OrderDate DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE())
    ,OrderTypeID INT NOT NULL --foreign key...
    ,Caption AS dbo.OrderCaption(OrderTypeID,OrderDate,ID)
);
GO

INSERT INTO YourOrder(OrderDate,OrderTypeID)
VALUES({ts'2016-01-01 23:23:00'},1)
     ,({ts'2016-02-02 12:12:00'},2)
     ,(GETDATE(),1);
GO

SELECT * FROM YourOrder
```

The result

```
ID  OrderDate               OrderTypeID     Caption
1   2016-01-01 23:23:00.000      1          NO/2016/01/00001
2   2016-02-02 12:12:00.000      2          SO/2016/02/00002
3   2016-10-23 23:16:23.990      1          NO/2016/10/00003
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's the cleanest and most logical solution so far. The only problem would still be resetting the number at the end of caption, but I will resolve it by storing last value in a service table in the database and running a job at the last day of each month and resetting it back to 0.

Comment: @MarcinBator, starting with SQL Server 2012 there is [`SEQUENCE` - find details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx).

Comment: @MarcinBator And read about [restarting a sequence here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878572.aspx)

Comment: Using a sequence instead of service table row and restarting it using a job would be a pretty sweet idea indeed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a computed column in your table definition which concatenates other values in your database into the kind of Identifier you're looking for.

Try this for a simplified example:-

```
CREATE TABLE Things ( 
  [Type of Order] varchar(10), 
  [Year] int,
  [Month] int,
  [Inc Number] int identity(1,1),
  [Identifier] as [Type of Order] + '/' + cast([Year] as varchar) + '/' + cast([Month] as varchar) + '/' + cast([Inc Number] as varchar)
)

insert into Things
values
('NO',2016,10)

select * from Things
```

If you wanted to do something more complex you could always use a trigger to update the column post insert or update.

Comment: Note that an IDENTITY does not guarantee that there won't be gaps in the created identifiers (eg, 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9 is entirely possible). Perhaps that is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @TT. That's true, but since in my application an order can never be deleted, it wouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: It's one way to do it, but I am storing types of orders in a different table (and table Order has field "Type" that references OrderTypes(Id)). I think I will have to write a stored procedure and store last order number in a settings table and have to find a way to reset the number when the month ends.

Comment: @MarcinBator Even then you have absolutely no guarantee at all that there won't be gaps.

Comment: @TT. Thanks for that comment, I did not know that.